# How to identify multiple USB-serial adapters under Ubuntu 10.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, usbserial, identification

I am reading data from multiple identical USB-serial adapters under Ubuntu 10.1.

On occasion, their /dev/tty path changes (eg if other USB devices are connected on startup).

I need a way of repeatedly referring to the same adapter through any such changes.

The devices all have the same serial numbers, according to udevadm.

I think the most likely option is to identify an adapter by which port it is connected to (they don't get  moved around).

I can find all sorts of interesting /dev paths that might work, but despite all the discussion about udev online, I can't locate a definitive statement about whether some of these paths are static if the device is plugged into a static port.

Comment: I found this superuser answer very useful: http://superuser.com/a/536648/27510

Answer (score 9):

There is a solution. It's better late then never ;)

Use the following `udev` rule to map `/dev/ttyUSB{?}` devices into the `/dev/usb-ports/%bus_id-%port_id` link.

Here is my `/etc/udev/rules.d/usb-parse-devpath.rules:`

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", PROGRAM="/etc/udev/rules.d/usb-parse-devpath.pm %p", SYMLINK+="usb-ports/%c"
```

And the `usb-parse-devpath.pm` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

@items = split("/", $ARGV[0]);
for ($i = 0; $i < @items; $i++) {
    if ($items[$i] =~ m/^usb[0-9]+$/) {
        print $items[$i + 1] . "\n";
        last;
    }
}
```

As you can see this helps us to create named links to `/dev/ttyUSB{?}` devices and place them at `/dev/usb-ports` in the following format: `bus_id-port_id`.

For example, the next command gives me the following:

```
$ udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/ttyUSB0
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
```

So, the `bus_id` is `3` and `port_id` is `1` and now I have following in my `/dev/usb-ports`:

```
$ ls -al /dev/usb-ports
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Май 12 00:26 3-1 -> ../ttyUSB0
```

Regards.

Comment: I found that changing

print $items[$i + 1]

to

print $items[$i + 2]

is more useful here; since both USB ports on the front of my computer seemed to map to '1-1' under the former!

Comment: Talk about over engineering! `ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SYMLINK+="usb-ports/tty-%s{../busnum}-%s{../devpath}"` does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Much like Ilya Matvejchikov's answer, a good solution is to add udev rules to do what you want with the device. Like you, I was having a similar problem. I had a UPS on a USB-to-multi-serial adapter and occasionally the system would switch around the /dev/tty numbers.

My solution was to create a rule to match the type of device by driver and port, then create a symbolic link to the port to which my UPS was attached. I used NUT to monitor the UPS, which was always plugged into the same physical port.

```
# File contents of /etc/udev/rules.d/75-nut-ups.rules
# Create /dev/nut-ups0 to use as a persistent serial device that can be used
# reliably by nut to communicate with a UPS attached to the system.
# The UPS is attached to the first port of a MosSemiconductor dual USB
# serial adapter.
KERNELS=="ttyUSB*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial", DRIVERS=="moschip7720", ATTRS{port_number}=="0", SYMLINK+="nut-ups0"
```

Now I configure NUT to always use a constant /dev/nut-ups0, as the serial port and the rule takes care of mapping properly when the usb-serial device is recognized.

You can use the lsusb command to find out the actual device name to use in the rule when it's plugged in.

Answer (score 2):

Look with `$ udevadm info -n /dev/ttyUSB0 -a` which port your USB device is plugged in. The variable KERNELS of one of the parent devices should be something like KERNELS=="1-1.2:1.0".

Create a udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.2:1.0", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB42"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.3:1.0", SYMLINK+="usb-serial"
```

and trigger udev

```
$ udevadm trigger
```

Answer (score 1):

I have many USB to Serial devices with *each* many ports and the solutions 
mentioned above did not quite did it for me.

The USB "KERNEL" was not enough in my case, but I found the port number.

I am aware that what I'm proposing now  might be considered an insane hack, 
but it works for me..
for now..

I would actually be pleased to see a more elegant suggestion 
that accomplish something similar..

So... Based on the previous answer form Ilya Matveychikov

File: /etc/udev/rules.d/usb-parse-devpath.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVNUM=$(echo "${1}" | rev | cut -d'/' -f4 | rev | tr -d '-' | tr -d '.' | tr -d ':')
PORTNUM=$(/sbin/udevadm info -a --path=${1} | grep "ATTRS{port_number}" | head -1 | cut -d'"' -f2)
PRODUCT=$(/sbin/udevadm info -a --path=${1} | grep "ATTRS{product}" | head -1 | cut -d'"' -f2 | tr -d '/' | tr ' ' '_')

NEWID="ttyUSB_${PRODUCT}_${DEVNUM}${PORTNUM}"

#echo "${NEWID} :: $1" >> /tmp/DEBUG_udev.txt

echo "$NEWID"
```

And File: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", PROGRAM="/etc/udev/rules.d/usb-parse-devpath.sh %p", SYMLINK+="TTYUSBs/%c"
```

The result look something like this:

```
# ls -l /dev/TTYUSBs

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_435100 -> ../ttyUSB20
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_435101 -> ../ttyUSB21
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_435102 -> ../ttyUSB22
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_435103 -> ../ttyUSB23
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_435104 -> ../ttyUSB24
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_435105 -> ../ttyUSB25
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_435106 -> ../ttyUSB26
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_435107 -> ../ttyUSB27
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_436100 -> ../ttyUSB28
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_436101 -> ../ttyUSB29
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_436102 -> ../ttyUSB30
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_436103 -> ../ttyUSB31
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_436104 -> ../ttyUSB32
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_436105 -> ../ttyUSB33
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_436106 -> ../ttyUSB34
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport416_436107 -> ../ttyUSB35
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport4_4341100 -> ../ttyUSB38
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport4_4341101 -> ../ttyUSB39
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport4_4342100 -> ../ttyUSB36
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport4_4342101 -> ../ttyUSB37
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport8_421100 -> ../ttyUSB2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport8_421101 -> ../ttyUSB3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport8_422100 -> ../ttyUSB4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport8_422101 -> ../ttyUSB5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport8_423100 -> ../ttyUSB18
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport8_423101 -> ../ttyUSB19
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport8_424100 -> ../ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Edgeport8_424101 -> ../ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_431100 -> ../ttyUSB6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_431101 -> ../ttyUSB7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_431102 -> ../ttyUSB8
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_431103 -> ../ttyUSB9
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_432100 -> ../ttyUSB10
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_432101 -> ../ttyUSB11
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_432102 -> ../ttyUSB12
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_432103 -> ../ttyUSB13
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_433100 -> ../ttyUSB14
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_433101 -> ../ttyUSB15
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_433102 -> ../ttyUSB16
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jan  5 18:46 ttyUSB_Keyspan_USA-49WG_433103 -> ../ttyUSB17
```

Answer (score 0):

usb-devices can get you the port number and the bus/dev enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

I too was searching this topic for a way to find which physical USB device was assigned/connected to a logical /dev device name.  So, after some trial and error, this is what worked best for me:

See what logical ttyUSBx devices exist (where x is 0, 1, 2...):

```
$ ls /dev
```

Show bus and device numbers for all usb-serial adapters:

```
$ lsusb
```

Finally, use:

```
$ udevadm info --name=ttyUSBx --attribute-walk | grep num
```

Now inspect the udevadm output to match the logical device name to the actual physical device.  Here my listing when I did it:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial     (UART) IC
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ udevadm info --name=ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk | grep num
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="812"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="5"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="115"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"

$ udevadm info --name=ttyUSB1 --attribute-walk | grep num
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="465"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="115"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
```

So, in my case, ttyUSB0 is associated with the device on bus2, device5, which is the Future Technology Devices International USB to Serial Adapter; and likewise, ttyUSB1 is associated with the device on bus2, device4, which is the Prolific Technology, Inc. USB to Serial adapter.

And as has been pointed out, the command:

```
$ usb-devices
```

Will get you the same info in a one-line manner.  I thought I'd post the details that helped me learn how the stuff worked behind the scenes...

Hope that was helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

> The devices all have the same serial numbers [..]

The usb-parse-devpath.pm addresses this by using the bus and port id of the adapter.